# I want to install scipy in debian10/armv7l environment, but it fails

Tags: python, pip, scipy, python-wheel

```bash
root@ZZZZZ:/home/dev/packages/scipy-1.9.3# pip install .
Processing /home/dev/packages/scipy-1.9.3
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [369 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "aarch64" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'platform_machine == "loongarch64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and (platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin") and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "loongarch64" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and (platform_system != "Windows" and platform_machine != "loongarch64") and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.11" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.12"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting meson-python>=0.9.0
        Using cached meson_python-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
      Collecting Cython<3.0,>=0.29.32
        Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)
      Collecting pybind11<2.11.0,>=2.4.3
        Using cached pybind11-2.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (216 kB)
      Collecting pythran<0.13.0,>=0.9.12
        Using cached pythran-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel<0.38.0
        Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.23.4
        Using cached numpy-1.23.4-cp39-cp39-linux_armv7l.whl
      Collecting pyproject-metadata>=0.5.0
        Using cached pyproject_metadata-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
      Collecting tomli>=1.0.0
        Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
      Collecting meson>=0.62.0
        Using cached meson-0.64.0-py3-none-any.whl (895 kB)
      Collecting ninja
        Using cached ninja-1.11.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting ply>=3.4
        Using cached ply-3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
      Collecting beniget~=0.4.0
        Using cached beniget-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.4 kB)
      Collecting gast~=0.5.0
        Using cached gast-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
      Collecting packaging>=19.0
        Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
      Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2
        Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): still running...
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): still running...
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): still running...
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): still running...
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): still running...
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [304 lines of output]


            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -- Trying "Ninja" generator
            --------------------------------
            ---------------------------
            ----------------------
            -----------------
            ------------
            -------
            --
            Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
            CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
              Running

               '/usr/bin/ninja' '--version'

              failed with:

               Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/usr/bin/ninja", line 5, in <module>
                  from ninja import ninja

              ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ninja'



            -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
            See also "/tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
            --
            -------
            ------------
            -----------------
            ----------------------
            ---------------------------
            --------------------------------
            -- Trying "Ninja" generator - failure
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator
            --------------------------------
            ---------------------------
            ----------------------
            -----------------
            ------------
            -------
            --
            Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
            -- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
            -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
            -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
            -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
            -- Detecting C compile features
            -- Detecting C compile features - done
            -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
            -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
            -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
            -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
            -- Detecting CXX compile features
            -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
            -- Configuring done
            -- Generating done
            -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_cmake_test_compile/build
            --
            -------
            ------------
            -----------------
            ----------------------
            ---------------------------
            --------------------------------
            -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator - success
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            Configuring Project
              Working directory:
                /tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-build
              Command:
                cmake /tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038 -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-install -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.9.7 -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-we6iehs1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/usr/bin/python3.9 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:PATH=/usr/lib/libpython3.9.a -DPython_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/usr/bin/python3.9 -DPython_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/usr -DPython_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPython_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER -DPython3_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/usr/bin/python3.9 -DPython3_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/usr -DPython3_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPython3_FIND_REGISTRY:STRING=NEVER -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release

            -- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
            -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
            -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
            -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
            -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
            -- Detecting C compile features
            -- Detecting C compile features - done
            -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
            -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
            -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
            -- Detecting CXX compile features
            -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
            -- *********************************************
            -- Ninja Python Distribution
            --
            --   BUILD_VERBOSE             : OFF
            --   RUN_NINJA_TEST            : ON
            --
            --   ARCHIVE_DOWNLOAD_DIR      : /tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-build
            --
            --     src_archive             : unix_source
            --     <src_archive>_url       : https://github.com/Kitware/ninja/archive/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.tar.gz
            --     <src_archive>_sha256    : 7ba84551f5b315b4270dc7c51adef5dff83a2154a3665a6c9744245c122dd0db
            -- *********************************************
            CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3075 (message):
              The DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option was not given and policy CMP0135 is
              not set.  The policy's OLD behavior will be used.  When using a URL
              download, the timestamps of extracted files should preferably be that of
              the time of extraction, otherwise code that depends on the extracted
              contents might not be rebuilt if the URL changes.  The OLD behavior
              preserves the timestamps from the archive instead, but this is usually not
              what you want.  Update your project to the NEW behavior or specify the
              DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option with a value of true to avoid this
              robustness issue.
            Call Stack (most recent call first):
              /usr/local/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:4185 (_ep_add_download_command)
              CMakeLists.txt:65 (ExternalProject_add)
            This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

            -- download_ninja_source - URL: https://github.com/Kitware/ninja/archive/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.tar.gz
            -- SuperBuild - CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: Release
            -- Configuring done
            -- Generating done
            CMake Warning:
              Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

                PYTHON_EXECUTABLE
                PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
                PYTHON_LIBRARY
                PYTHON_VERSION_STRING
                Python3_EXECUTABLE
                Python3_FIND_REGISTRY
                Python3_INCLUDE_DIR
                Python3_ROOT_DIR
                Python_EXECUTABLE
                Python_FIND_REGISTRY
                Python_INCLUDE_DIR
                Python_ROOT_DIR
                SKBUILD


            -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-build
            [  5%] Creating directories for 'download_ninja_source'
            [ 11%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'download_ninja_source'
            -- Downloading...
               dst='/tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-build/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.tar.gz'
               timeout='none'
               inactivity timeout='none'
            -- Using src='https://github.com/Kitware/ninja/archive/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.tar.gz'
            -- verifying file...
                   file='/tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-build/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.tar.gz'
            -- Downloading... done
            -- extracting...
                 src='/tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-build/v1.11.1.g95dee.kitware.jobserver-1.tar.gz'
                 dst='/tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/Ninja-src'
            -- extracting... [tar xfz]
            -- extracting... [analysis]
            -- extracting... [rename]
            -- extracting... [clean up]
            -- extracting... done
            [ 16%] No update step for 'download_ninja_source'
            [ 22%] No patch step for 'download_ninja_source'
            [ 27%] No configure step for 'download_ninja_source'
            [ 33%] No build step for 'download_ninja_source'
            [ 38%] No install step for 'download_ninja_source'
            [ 44%] Completed 'download_ninja_source'
            [ 44%] Built target download_ninja_source
            [ 50%] Creating directories for 'build_ninja'
            [ 55%] No download step for 'build_ninja'
            [ 61%] No update step for 'build_ninja'
            [ 66%] No patch step for 'build_ninja'
            [ 72%] Performing configure step for 'build_ninja'
            loading initial cache file /tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-build/build_'ninja-prefix/tmp/build_ninja-cache-Release.cmake
            -- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0'
            -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3'.0
            -- Detecting C compiler ABI info'
            -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
            -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
            -- Detecting C compile features
            -- Detecting C compile features - done
            -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
            -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
            -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
            -- Detecting CXX compile features
            -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
            -- IPO / LTO enabled
            -- Performing Test flag_no_deprecated
            -- Performing Test flag_no_deprecated - Success
            -- Performing Test flag_color_diag
            -- Performing Test flag_color_diag - Success
            CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:49 (message):
              re2c was not found; changes to src/*.in.cc will not affect your build.


            -- Looking for fork
            -- Looking for fork - found
            -- Looking for pipe
            -- Looking for pipe - found
            -- Configuring done
            -- Generating done
            -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-build/Ninja-build
            [ 77%] Performing build step for 'build_ninja'
            [  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja-re2c.dir/src/depfile_parser.cc.o
            [  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja-re2c.dir/src/lexer.cc.o
            [  2%] Built target libninja-re2c
            [  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/build_log.cc.o
            [  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/build.cc.o
            [  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/clean.cc.o
            [  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/clparser.cc.o
            [ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/dyndep.cc.o
            [ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/dyndep_parser.cc.o
            [ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/debug_flags.cc.o
            [ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/deps_log.cc.o
            [ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/disk_interface.cc.o
            [ 17%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/edit_distance.cc.o
            [ 19%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/eval_env.cc.o
            [ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/graph.cc.o
            [ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/graphviz.cc.o
            [ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/json.cc.o
            [ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/line_printer.cc.o
            [ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/manifest_parser.cc.o
            [ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/metrics.cc.o
            [ 29%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/missing_deps.cc.o
            [ 31%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/parser.cc.o
            [ 32%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/state.cc.o
            [ 34%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/status.cc.o
            [ 35%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/string_piece_util.cc.o
            [ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/tokenpool-gnu-make.cc.o
            [ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/util.cc.o
            [ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/version.cc.o
            [ 41%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/subprocess-posix.cc.o
            [ 43%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libninja.dir/src/tokenpool-gnu-make-posix.cc.o
            [ 43%] Built target libninja
            [ 44%] Generating build/browse_py.h
            [ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja.dir/src/ninja.cc.o
            [ 47%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja.dir/src/browse.cc.o
            [ 49%] Linking CXX executable ninja
            [ 49%] Built target ninja
            [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/build_log_test.cc.o
            [ 52%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/build_test.cc.o
            [ 53%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/clean_test.cc.o
            [ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/clparser_test.cc.o
            [ 56%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/depfile_parser_test.cc.o
            [ 58%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/deps_log_test.cc.o
            [ 59%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/disk_interface_test.cc.o
            [ 61%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/dyndep_parser_test.cc.o
            [ 62%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/edit_distance_test.cc.o
            [ 64%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/graph_test.cc.o
            [ 65%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/json_test.cc.o
            [ 67%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/lexer_test.cc.o
            [ 68%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/manifest_parser_test.cc.o
            [ 70%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/missing_deps_test.cc.o
            [ 71%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/ninja_test.cc.o
            [ 73%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/state_test.cc.o
            [ 74%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/string_piece_util_test.cc.o
            [ 76%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/subprocess_test.cc.o
            [ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/test.cc.o
            [ 79%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/tokenpool_test.cc.o
            [ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ninja_test.dir/src/util_test.cc.o
            [ 82%] Linking CXX executable ninja_test
            [ 82%] Built target ninja_test
            [ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/build_log_perftest.dir/src/build_log_perftest.cc.o
            [ 85%] Linking CXX executable build_log_perftest
            [ 85%] Built target build_log_perftest
            [ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/canon_perftest.dir/src/canon_perftest.cc.o
            [ 88%] Linking CXX executable canon_perftest
            [ 88%] Built target canon_perftest
            [ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/clparser_perftest.dir/src/clparser_perftest.cc.o
            [ 91%] Linking CXX executable clparser_perftest
            [ 91%] Built target clparser_perftest
            [ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/depfile_parser_perftest.dir/src/depfile_parser_perftest.cc.o
            [ 94%] Linking CXX executable depfile_parser_perftest
            [ 94%] Built target depfile_parser_perftest
            [ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hash_collision_bench.dir/src/hash_collision_bench.cc.o
            [ 97%] Linking CXX executable hash_collision_bench
            [ 97%] Built target hash_collision_bench
            [ 98%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/manifest_parser_perftest.dir/src/manifest_parser_perftest.cc.o
            [100%] Linking CXX executable manifest_parser_perftest
            [100%] Built target manifest_parser_perftest
            [ 83%] Stripping CMake executables
            [ 88%] Running Ninja test suite
            make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/build_ninja.dir/build.make:120: build_ninja-prefix/src/build_ninja-stamp/build_ninja-run_ninja_test_suite] Error 130
            make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:111: CMakeFiles/build_ninja.dir/all] Error 2
            make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-we6iehs1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 640, in setup
                cmkr.make(make_args, install_target=cmake_install_target, env=env)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-we6iehs1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 670, in make
                self.make_impl(clargs=clargs, config=config, source_dir=source_dir, install_target=install_target, env=env)
              File "/tmp/pip-build-env-we6iehs1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 701, in make_impl
                raise SKBuildError(

            An error occurred while building with CMake.
              Command:
                cmake --build . --target install --config Release --
              Install target:
                install
              Source directory:
                /tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038
              Working directory:
                /tmp/pip-install-h317wd1u/ninja_ea80f17956454895b214a420d61cc038/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-build
            Please check the install target is valid and see CMake's output for more information.
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
      Failed to build ninja
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Execution Environment is

```bash
root@ZZZZZ:/home/dev/packages/scipy-1.9.3# python3 -V
Python 3.9.7
root@ZZZZZ:/home/dev/packages/scipy-1.9.3# pip list
Cython     0.29.32
joblib     1.2.0
meson      0.64.0
ninja      1.11.1
numpy      1.23.4
pip        22.3.1
setuptools 65.6.0
wheel      0.38.4
root@ZZZZZ:/home/dev/packages/scipy-1.9.3# /usr/bin/ninja --version
1.11.1.git.kitware.jobserver-1
root@ZZZZZ:/home/dev/packages/scipy-1.9.3# cmake --version
cmake version 3.25.0
```

I really want to install pandas and scikit-learn, but I get an error.
So I installed them individually and found that scipy is the cause.
Also, the default is numpy==1.19.3, but I changed it to numpy==1.23.4. (pyproject.toml)

Why can't it recognize ninja if it is already in there?
Is there a switch to make this work?
If it needs to be modified, which module is it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that happens with your pip version. Try to downgrade it to pip=19.0 and try again to see if it works. Also you can try the solution [here](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/8951#issuecomment-1207196457) if downgrading pip doesn't work.

Comment: I tried with pip=19.0.3. However, nothing changed.

The contents of "/usr/bin/ninja" were python scripts (since when?). 
So I overwrote "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ninja/data/bin/ninja", and tried pip install. Then got "Try the Ninja generator" response to "success". However, the error content is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Bypass the compilation error of Ninja through pip by installing it with the system package manager.

For example: `apt-get install ninja-build`

--

Note that the ninja detection works by running `/usr/bin/ninja`, but your installation might be `/usr/bin/ninja-build`.

Try to symlink it: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/bin/ninja-build`.